# override screen when move another scree in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am new in swift.I want to move one screen to another but problem is when I go to another screen,old screen overrides in new screen.

here is my code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            let appsDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
            appsDelegate?.window!!.rootViewController = nil
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("launcherEntry") as! UINavigationController

            appsDelegate?.window!!.rootViewController = nextViewController
        }
```

Comment: are you use the  storyboard connection ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `UINavigationController`, you should *push* the second view(screen) onto the first one. Check out the [offical guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/).

Answer (score 0):

According to your code old screen overrides because you have not a push  a `UIViewController` into navigation controller.
Here you destroyee the exiting controller then set a new controller. So that previos controller is move from the memory.

Please show [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) for the UINavigationController.

**Update:**
Please use following code for set a root view controller then you can push view controller easily.

```
    let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
    let rootViewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_LoginVC") as! LoginVC
    navigationController.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Comment: i will push UIViewController into navigation controller than display wrraper data nil

Comment: display error Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'window'

Comment: put above code in appDeleget then push view controller directly as self.navigationcontroller.push......

Answer (score 0):

As you are new , i will explain what will happen when your code will be executed.

App delegate will hold the current instance of our application. Setting root view controller is setting Main view controller of your application.
SO basically your code will replace the previous view controller with next one.
 Now what you have to do,
We have Navigation controller to manage our navigation stack, that allow us to go back from where have initiated.

If you are Using storyboard , add your view controller into NavigationController, if you already know then ignore or follow this
SELECT your first view controller GOTO Editor in Xcode menu > Select EMBED IN option > NAVIGATION CONTROLLER. this will add your first view into navigation controller.

Now when you want to display next view controller, There are two ways to do so,
1)Using segue from Storyboard

1. Right click from view/button from where you want to show next view.
2. drag it to the next view controller and release the right click.
3. Select push

2)Programatically
 you don't have to set root view controller, just push the next view controller in navigation controller you have

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("launcherEntry") as! UINavigationController
```

Above line will intimate the textview controller, now we have to push this view controller, we can achieve this with

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```